# Unable to save qty in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4

I am creating product programmatically. Following is the code

```
 $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

 try {
  $product->setName('Test Product');
  $product->setTypeId('simple');
  $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
  $product->setSku('test-SKU');
  $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
  $product->setVisibility(4);
  $product->setPrice(array(1));
  $product->setImage('/testimg/test.jpg');
  $product->setSmallImage('/testimg/test.jpg');
  $product->setThumbnail('/testimg/test.jpg');
  $product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
        'manage_stock' => 1,
        'min_sale_qty' => 1,
        'max_sale_qty' => 2,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 100
    )
);

$product->save();
```

I have also used "setQuantityAndStockStatus" but qty is not saved.

Comment: as per your code, qty is working and saving. in fact price is not saving and need to set product enable as well!

Comment: You need to use this class to set the product inventory. Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface reference link : https://webkul.com/blog/update-product-stock-programmatically-in-magento2/